# Decoding only part of a JSON using Codable protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I have a `JSON` which contains an `array` of `dictionaries` and I decode it, using `Swift`'s `JSONDecoder` class.

I wonder, is it possible to make the class to decode only some `dictionaries`, not all, for example (maybe based on some criteria)? I guess, this might be useful if the `array` contains many `dictionaries`, but you don't want all of them but only a single one.

If you know how to do this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you have already received the body of the call with all the data. If you don't need all the data i think this should be the work of the backend developer to send the proper needed data for you. Like using paging for example while sending the data and stuff like that. Take care akhber jan and good luck.

Comment: If you want to filter the results, it's going to be much easier and cleaner to let `JSONDecoder` parse everything and then filter the results once Sure, you can write your own `init(from:)` to do this, but it will be more elegant to just filter the results after you've parsed them into Swift objects.

Comment: @KeghamK., so, if the file is already inside a project (I don't download it from the Internet), I can't do that, right? Because, I think, if it'd been from some server, it would have been easier to do this.

Comment: @Rob, well, I already have all the `strutters` being ready for parsing the `JSON` to a Swift object. The problem is, in that case I get an array of a particular object. Of course, fetching the desired structure from that array is easy, but what if there are a lot of dictionaries inside my JSON (I know, this isn't an issue if it is downloaded from a server where I can filter and get the exact one that I need. In my case, it is in a project, for now). In that case, I have to parse all objects just to find the one that I need from the array.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan as Rob said it is more elegant and cleaner to parse the data and loop through it and set your arrays from the data you only need from the body you received. You can use [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to do that.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for making it clear. P.S. I have far less than millions. I was just wondering how to do that :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically one can write an [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init) method that manually gets the container for the decoder and then get the "nested" container (e.g., [`nestedUnkeyedContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyeddecodingcontainer/2893319-nestedunkeyedcontainer)), and manually decode the items within that collection, only adding the ones you want. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for an introduction to writing `init(from:)` methods.

But I would discourage you from doing that. It's going to be much simpler and logical to parse the whole JSON and then `filter` the resulting collection to distill it down to the ones you want.

Unless you have a lot of records (e.g. millions?) where the parsing overhead becomes observable, I would suggest performing a `decode` the entire JSON and then `filter` your array. This will require far less code and is the more logical approach.

And if you had that many records, before I contemplated the `init(from:)` kludge, I would reconsider using JSON at all. I'd use CoreData or SQLite or something like that which is better suited for dynamic filtering of data as it is being extracted.